# C++11: Template programming

Tags: c++, c++11, template-meta-programming

I have some problem. What is meaning next code?

```
template<typename> 
struct function_traits; // (1)

template<typename ClassType,
             typename ReturnType,
             typename... Arguments>
struct function_traits<ReturnType(ClassType::*)(Arguments...) const> { // (2)
        ...
};

template<typename T>
struct function_traits : public function_traits<decltype(&T::operator())> {}; 
// (3) Why here inheritance?
```

Thanks!

Comment: It's a class template that's partially specialized for two kinds of types: Member function pointer types, and class types that have a call operator. The latter specialization is simply defined in terms of the former (using inheritance).

Comment: Remember that not all inheritance is about virtual destructors and public Animals. Inheritance is a very general tool with many diverse applications.

Comment: What part of the code are you not understanding? Is that a keyword, a a specific use of a keyword? Have you read tutorials on template programming yet? What *do* you know/understand? [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thanks! I understood :D.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's understandable that you find this a mystery. Most of us do at the beginning.

First:

```
template<typename> 
struct function_traits; // (1)
```

This declares the general form of a template class which has one template parameter, which is a type (class X, struct Y, int, float, std::string, whatever). Note that at present the template is declared, but no classes can be instantiated from it, because the template has no specialisations. Not even a default one.

Second:

```
template<typename ClassType,
             typename ReturnType,
             typename... Arguments>
struct function_traits<ReturnType(ClassType::*)(Arguments...) const> { // (2)
        ...
    using result_type = ReturnType; // capture the template type into a typedef in the class namespace
};
```

This defines a partial specialisation of the template `function_traits<typename T>` where T is any member function pointer of any class which returns any return type and takes any number of arguments. Because `ReturnType` has been assigned a template parameter, it means that the definition of this class is allowed to refer to it as a type, thus deducing the `result_type` of the member function.

However, at this stage the specialisation is not useful because a caller would need to specify the complete function pointer at the call site, like this: `function_traits<&SomeClass::someFunction>` and dealing with overloads would be tricky.

Now the third part makes an 'interface' specialisation which says that for any class `T`, `function_traits<T>` shall be derived from `function_traits<&T::operator()>`.

```
template<typename T>
struct function_traits : public function_traits<decltype(&T::operator())> {}; 
// (3) Why here inheritance?
```

Because there is such a specific match in the template expansion, it will only be expanded for types that have a call operator (`operator()`). The base class is providing the return type, from the second specialisation, so this template is able to capture the return type of any type which has a call operator. Because this class is derived from the actual class that captures the return type, `result_type` is also part of this class's scope.

now we can write:

```
struct Foo {
    int operator()();
};

using foo_ret = function_traits<Foo>::result_type;
```

And foo_ret will be `int`.

Still confused? Welcome to your first 6 months of template programming.

Comment: Wow! Thanks! For for the detailed explanation :)